# ImportError: cannot import name 'show_config'

Tags: python, scipy

i don't know why i get this error even i installed correctly the libraries:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/Doc/Diagnostic-Technology/Browser.py", line 4, in <module>
  import scipy.stats as stat
 File "D:\Doc\Diagnostic-Technology\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
  from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config 
ImportError: cannot import name 'show_config'
```

packages wich i imported :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stat
import math as math
```

help please!

Comment: I take it that your script's name isn't `numpy`, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem and solved it this way

1. find any file named as "numpy.py" in your script directory and change it into another name.
2. delete any file named as "numpy.pyc" or any other file generated while compiling your code.